# Copy of object identifier and reference to object identifier - which one should be used in real app?

Tags: php, oop

In the below example, any operation done by `$instance2` and `$instance3` modifies original object.

My question is:

If a copy of an original object identifier and a reference to the original object identifier does same job, which one should be used in real applications?

What are the pros and cons of using a copy of object identifier and of using a reference to the object identifier?

I read the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) but am unable to differentiate in terms of usage because both do the same job.

```
$instance1 = new test(1);
$instance2 = $instance1;
$instance3 =& $instance1;

//$instance1 -> original object identifier of the new object.
//$instance2 -> copy of object identifier $instance1
//$instance3 -> reference to the object identifier $instance1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$instance2` has a copy of the identifier to the object test. So, it contains the same as `$instance1`.
`$instance3` contains a reference to `$instance1`. The difference would be the following:

```
$instance1 = new Test();
$instance2 = $instance1;
$instance3 = & $instance1;

var_dump($instance1 instanceof Test); // True
var_dump($instance2 instanceof Test); // True
var_dump($instance3 instanceof Test); // True

$instance3 = new AnotherTest();

var_dump($instance1 instanceof AnotherTest); // True
var_dump($instance2 instanceof AnotherTest); // False
var_dump($instance3 instanceof AnotherTest); // True
```

The same output would be returned if `$instance1` was changed instead of `$instance3`.

But if we did the following:

```
$instance1 = new Test();
$instance2 = $instance1;
$instance3 = & $instance1;

$instance2 = new AnotherTest();

var_dump($instance1 instanceof AnotherTest); // False
var_dump($instance2 instanceof AnotherTest); // True
var_dump($instance3 instanceof AnotherTest); // False
```

So:

Modification of a variable which has been passed by reference or assigned by reference (using the `&` operand) or of the variable to which it references, modifies both, while modification of a copied variable modifies only the given variable.

Still, you must remember that what `$instance1` keeps is an identifier of the object, so:

```
$instance1 = new StdClass();
$instance2 = $instance1;

$instance1->my_property = 1;
var_dump($instance2->my_property); // Output: 1
```

Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: You examples makes sense but you should not use 'pointer' word in PHP.

Comment: I used the "poitner" word because the main differences between them are precisely how the engine handles them... I didn't know how to phrase it differently.

Comment: The right term is object identifier: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: This article includes some important information on the negative performance impact of using references vs. using copied object identifiers, because of the way PHP's runtime works. In general, the article advises against using references. http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html

Answer (score 0):

With objects in PHP5, instead of the entire object, only the object identifier is copied. This makes that you do not need to reference to the same value any more, and instead can just copy the identifier to refer to the same object. Use it to your advantage; you can get rid of the ampersands.

An important difference is that assignment to a variable reference affect the original variable, whereas assignment to a copied object identifier does not. Only modifications to the object would. If you want to use OO in an intuitive way, this would be a reason *not* to use object references. Example:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->name = "A";

$b = new stdClass();
$b->name = "B";

// $x is a copy of the object identifier in $a
$x = $a;
// $y is a reference to $a
$y = &$a;

// this will not affect $a
$x = $b;
echo $a->name; // 'A'

// this will affect $a
$y = $b;
echo $a->name; // 'B'
```

See also this article on why the use of (ampersand) references should be avoided:

http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html

Comment: Can you point any significant difference between them? not using & is just a syntax benefit. Otherwise both serves the same purpose.

Comment: I added an example illustrating why it is a good thing to take advantage of object identifiers and to avoid using variable references i.c.w. objects.